# Switch Statement Error **control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]**

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out the reasons why this is not working correctly, but I feel like I've covered every case I need. I can't seem to find the **"control reaches end of non-void function"** error. Here is my switch statement:

```
static unsigned int sizeIndex(size_t size) {
    int determine_size = 0;
    switch(determine_size) {
        case 0:
            if (size < 16) {
                return 0;
            }
        case 1:
            if ((size >= 16) && (size < 32)) {
                return 1;
            }
        case 2:
            if ((size >= 32) && (size < 64)) {
                return 2;
            }
        case 3:
            if ((size >= 64) && (size < 128) ) {
                return 3;
            }
        case 4:
            if ((size >= 128) && (size < 256)) {
                return 4;
            }
        case 5:
            if ((size >= 256) && (size < 512)) {
                return 5;
            }
        case 6:
            if ((size >= 512) && (size < 1024)) {
                return 6;
            }
        case 7:
            if ((size >= 1024) && (size < 2048)) {
                return 7;
            }
        case 8:
            if ((size >= 2048) && (size < 4096)) {
                return 8;
            }
        case 9:
            if ((size >= 4096) && (size < 8192)) {
                return 9;
            }
        case 10:
            if ((size >= 8192) && (size < 16384)) {
                return 10;
            }
        case 11: 
            if ((size >= 16384) && (size < 32768)) {
                return 11;
            }
        case 12:
            if (size >= 32768) {
                return 12;
            }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see a reason why this would throw a " control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]" error?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a shortcoming of the compiler. It is unable to deduce that one of the `return` statements must be executed, even though one must be. As the code currently stands, you could change the final case to `return 12;`, and the behavior would be identical and the compiler would be sated. However, if the `int determine_size = 0;` at the beginning were changed, the behavior with and without this change of the final case would not be identical—execution could indeed fall through the `switch` to the end of the function…

Comment: because you do not have a return statement at the end of the function, in case none of those returns above match.

Comment: … Do you have plans for this function to operate with different values of `determine_size`? If so, what do you want it to return when none of the executed tests evaluate to true? Because, if `determine_size` is greater than 0, execution will fall through the `switch` for values of `size` less than the threshold of the first test, so you should have a `return` statement to cover that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `switch` is entirely useless (because `determine_size` is always `0` and you don't use `break`), so you have a sequence of `if` statements that cover the entire range of `size`. `gcc` doesn't appear to check for this. Even the following warns `control reaches end of non-void function`:

```
if (size >= 4) {
   return 0;
}
if (size < 4) {
   return 1;
}
```

But while the reason given by warning it gave wasn't correct, there's plenty to warn about in that code.

Fixed:

```
static unsigned int sizeIndex(size_t size) {
    if      (size <    16) { return  0; }
    else if (size <    32) { return  1; }
    else if (size <    64) { return  2; }
    else if (size <   128) { return  3; }
    else if (size <   256) { return  4; }
    else if (size <   512) { return  5; }
    else if (size <  1024) { return  6; }
    else if (size <  2048) { return  7; }
    else if (size <  4096) { return  8; }
    else if (size <  8192) { return  9; }
    else if (size < 16384) { return 10; }
    else if (size < 32768) { return 11; }
    else                   { return 12; }
}
```

Or:

```
static unsigned int sizeIndex(size_t size) {
    unsigned int rv = 0;
    size_t threshold = 16;
    while (size >= threshold && threshold <= 32768) {
       ++rv;
       threshold <<= 1;
    }

    return rv;
}
```